# Unity / Cloned Enemies don't work as intended / C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a terrain with two enemies that I placed and a plane that I have given a script to spawn enemies continuously (basically wave defence without towers)

The two enemies I placed work as intended, killing them will give experience and coming into contact with them cost the player some health.

But the ones spawned by my scripted plane don't grant experience on a kill, the only reason they do health damage on contact is because I set the collision to look for a tag of "Enemy" which they have.

```
# THE SCRIPT FOR THE ENEMY-SPAWNING PLANE

IEnumerator Spawner()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);

    while(!stop)
    {
        randEnemy = Random.Range(0, 2);
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x), 2, Random.Range(-spawnValues.z, spawnValues.z));

        Instantiate(enemies[randEnemy], spawnPosition + transform.TransformPoint(0, 0, 0), gameObject.transform.rotation);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnWait);
    }
}
```

---

```
# THE SCRIPT WHICH CALLS FOR EXPERIENCE TO BE GIVEN (Enemy as GameObject)

void Dead()
{
    _characterXP.GainExp(120);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

---

```
# THE SCRIPT WHICH GIVES THE PLAYER EXPERIENCE (CharacterXP as GameObject)

public void GainExp(float expThatWasGained)
{
    CurrentExp += expThatWasGained;
}
```

I'm still pretty new to Unity and C# so if there is anything else that's needed I can provide it, I have checked all relevant objects to make sure the relevant things are connected correctly, and if they didn't work then it would affect the original enemies, the issue is only in regards to the spawned enemies that get named ENEMY(Clone)

---

**EDIT**

[image: The Prefab]
The Prefab ^

---

[image: The Pre-Spawned Enemy Mid-Game]
The Pre-Spawned Enemy Mid-Game^

---

[image: The Clone Enemy Mid-Game]
The Clone Enemy Mid-Game^

Comment: Do your instantiated enemies have the correct script on them?

Comment: You said, "in regards to the **spawned** enemies".  Does this mean that the two you start with are already placed on the terrain?  If so, look for the inconsistency.  Make sure your enemy Prefab is tagged with "Enemy" or create a new prefab. If this is your setup - remove the original two and make sure you Instantiate all of them.

Comment: Yep, they are derived from a prefab of which the two pre-spawned enemies also derive from.
All the necessary things have been filled in, there are no warnings or errors that appear when I kill a clone, it's as if they are exempt from those lines of code but there is no way that they don't have the script attached.

Comment: @jiveturkey I just tried deleting my two pre-spawned ones and it made no difference.
I also forgot to mention I do have two prefabs, there are two different types of enemies (simple and boss) I have two simples placed on the terrain for start-up but no bosses yet all monsters spawned by the plane act the exact same way in that they don't grant exp on kill.

Comment: Can you provide:
A picture of the prefab selected. A picture of an instantiated object in scene view during playing, while having the object selected

Comment: Added the screenshots in an edit at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Your second screenshot of the prespawned, who is it's parent? Your instantiated monster has no parent. Could be that it might affect your scripts.

Comment: @Immorality I just had a look, looks like I renamed the two pre-spawned to Enemy because when I open it up to look at the children it is just the body parts, I just dragged the prefab as a pre-loaded too but kept the name Monster and they didn't give exp on kill either so now I know its something to do with either the naming or something to do with the prefab but I cannot tell which.

Comment: Well, who and where is the death function called?

Comment: If that doesn't work, something that has bitten me before, don't Destroy the object in the Dead method.  You can getting into threading/timing issues and the Monster objects will be Destroyed before the call to GainExp completes.

Comment: void dead() is called in EnemyHealth

I was just doing some testing and if I drag my FPS controller from the scene onto the pre-spawned Monster I just added then that gives Exp too. So I tried the same with the prefab but it won't let me just drag a scene component into a prefab.

Before I do it I just wanna see if my reasoning is sound:
I destroy the current Monster Prefab and replace it with my now working version and do the same with the Boss prefab and it should work correctly right?

Comment: Okay, so it didn't work- it doesn't remember the FPSController from the scene and asks for a new one, which is when I looked at the FPSController Prefab I have and it has a lot of differences to the onScene one because I can't drag the UI elements onto it (the exp bar for example) Should I make these UI elements a prefab? And if I do will it change anything from the scene or...?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign scene objects to prefab property fields. You can only assign other prefab (or assets) into the prefab property slots. 
To assign a scene object to your enemy script, you need to find it at runtime.

In your enemy's Start method, find the fpscontroller

```
void Start()
{
    _characterXP = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<FPSController>();
}
```

I think this will solve your problem

Comment: I just tried this, but it comes up with an: error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FPSController' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? is there something I need to add at the top with using  UnityEngine; ? Because the Quick Actions isn't finding a solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Not the most intelligent way of doing this, but I was on a tight schedule and the method works.

I created two prisons outside of the playable area and put one of each enemy inside of it and then referred to these two trapped individuals in my Monster Spawner (The Plane) instead of the prefabs and now I gain the right amount of exp per kill.